# Differentiate between manual and auto scroll in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

This might be a basic question but I have a situation where I've setup auto scrolling of recyclerview (Combination of Looping through data objects, view holders and applying scroll to position).

The oversight I made was about how to handle the situation when user tries to regain control over the scroll ?

**The problem:** How to differentiate between user trying to gain back control (with manual scrolling) vs my loop trying to scroll through ?

**Solution already tried:** Use custom layout manager, override calculatespeedperpixel and provide custom value. Now when the user tries to manually scroll, if the scroll speed doesn't match my custom value, we can assume it was the user who scrolled.

*This was a hackish workaround and wasn't fool proof always*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the touch listener for the recyclerview and when it triggeres you pause scrolling  and after some time trigger automatically.

Comment: It really helps to not overthink/over engineer a solution. This was insightful!

Comment: Glad ti be helpful @RmK